# Colocar flag na linha de comandos bash shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell-script, shell

Estou a tentar colocar uma flag que consiga ordenar ou fazer shuffle do output, mas só consegui fazer isso dentro codigo e pretendia que funcionasse quando se colocasse a flag no comando para correr o ficheiro, por exemplo ./bash.sh -r.

Comment: Utilize [getopts](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/752a690f-8e93-4948-b7a3-c060117e8665/entry/getopts_scripts_mais_profissionais?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Um pequeno exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in                ## definir o pósprocessador
  -r)  pp="shuf" ;;         # -r    shuffle 
  -s)  pp="sort" ;;         # -s    sort
   *)  pp="cat -n"  ;;      # default numera linhas
esac

function proc(){
  ls /bin                 ## ... produzir um output
}

proc | $pp
```

Comment: Até agora tenho isto e quando executo o comando continua a não me ordenar o output, neste caso um conjunto de links                    
    `target="$1"; wget -qO- "http://reddit.com/r/${target}" | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*"

case"$1" in
  -r)  pp="shuf" ;;
  -s)  pp="sort" ;;
   *)  pp="cat -n"  ;;
esac `